# Allure and Hapi Lab coverage reports

Tags: coffeescript, hapi.js, allure

I am in the process of trying to figure out if we can use the Allure plugin for TeamCity to show code coverage, and completed tests in our build pipeline.

All of the tests for our web services are written in CoffeeScript using Hapijs Lab.

When we run the tests now we use 'npm test' and once the tests complete a coverage.html document is generated.

Does anyone know of a way that I can convert this coverage.html report into a format that Allure would understand? From what I have read it seems that Allure is expecting XML. Does anyone have experience in converting an existing report into XML?

Answer (score 2):

When you run your lab tests you can add the flag:

```
lab tests.js --reporter junit
```

And you will get a junit style xml output.

Then you need to make sure you have the JUnit adapter installed for allure. You can find info about that here:

https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-core/wiki/JUnit

Comment: Allure uses its own XML format it will not work with standard JUnit XML.

Comment: @vania-pooh There is an adapter for JUnit 4 (which I link to in my answer)

Comment: @apiguy: yes, but this adapter is expected to be used during test execution of the Java tests. This adapter generates Allure XML itself and does nothing with junit XML you're talking about. I'm saying this as Allure core developer.